NgbDatepicker days names are displaced by one day
The days in my datepicker as displaced by 1 day. Monday says Sunday and so on...
I changed the "firstDayOfWeek" attribute and it moves with the error.
I localized the app to "es" (The app is in spanish) and there was no change.
I desinstalled and reinstalled the ngbboostrap.
I entered their site and the datepicker also shows the same mistake.
Dom (Sun) should be Lun (Mon)
I'm using angular 18 with standalone components
I changed the localization. Updated the package. Even their own site shows me the same problem.
July 15th is Monday, not Sunday

Looks like this is based on the local timezone of your browser, and has been raised as issue 4729, with a PR to fix it raised by @sorin-davidoi in June but not yet (at the time of writing) merged.
